# Unzip to folder in internal storage

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a folder in internal storage called "unzip" and then unzip a file into the internal storage "unzip folder". Not sure what i'm doing wrong? If you could please explain what's wrong it'd be great! Thanks

**Edit: The issues is that I don't think the folder is being created and the file is also not being unzipped.**

```
public void send(View view) {
    try {
        File mydir = this.getDir("unzip", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);//create folder in internal storage
        unzip(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), job_no, getFilesDir() + "/unzip/");
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}

public void unzip(String filepath, String filename, String unzip_path) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filepath + filename);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

    try {
        ZipEntry ze;
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int count;

            String filename_temp = ze.getName();
            File fmd = new File(filepath + filename_temp);

            if (!fmd.getParentFile().exists()) {
                fmd.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }

            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(unzip_path + filename_temp);

            while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                fout.write(bytes);
                baos.reset();
            }

            fout.close();
            //}
        }
    } finally {
        zis.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you might want to explain what isn't working.  Although the one thing I see immediately is  File mydir = this.getDir("unzip", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);//create folder in internal storage     That won't actually make the directory.

Comment: Yeah that's probably a good idea lol

Answer (score 0):

This will get absolute storage device.

```
final static String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
```

Comment: That'll work for external storage, but I want it on the internal storage. Thanks

Comment: If u don't have sdard it will get internal storage path and if u have sdcard it will take external storage path. More important it will accept both.

Comment: Okay so i've fixed the folder creation, the folder now creates properly....but the unzip function is still not working..